How to use KAPT to generate test-only classes from classes in main source set?
I've implemented annotation processor to generate test classes from classes in my main source set. Generated classes contain MockK dependencies, that I don't want and don't need in my main source set.
If I use following in build.gradle
kapt project(':codegen')

classes are generated, but project does not compile due to lacking MockK dependencies.
On the other hand, if I use
kaptTest project(':codegen')

classes are not generated. Annotation processor is invoked, but it does not process classes from which new classes have to be generated. It only processes test classes.
My goal is to process classes from main source set in annotation processor, but use them only during tests.
What should I change in build.gradle to achieve this?

I ended up using kapt project(':codegen'), but with additional configuration.
In build.gradle I've added additional kapt config to set additional parameter with output dir for my generated code.
kapt {
  arguments {
    arg("mycodegen.output", "$buildDir/generated/mycodegen")
  }
}

I use this value with
processingEnv.options["mycodegen.output"]

So in the end, annotation processor is run during main code compilation, on the main code, but generated code is saved in custom directory, which by default is not included in any source set.
To use this code in tests I simply add output dir to test source set:
sourceSets {
  test.java.srcDirs += "${buildDir}/generated/mycodegen"
}

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, because code is generated with every main code compilation, however it works.
